# gpssh-exkeys -f hostlist don't work.Greenplum

Tags: ubuntu, greenplum

Ubuntu 18.04LTS
I try connect GreenPlum on Ubuntu.
https://greenplum.org/install-greenplum-oss-on-ubuntu/

An error occurred at the stage "Edit gpinitsystem Configuration File". I do not understand why.
"Failed to execute ssh. Failed to resolve hostname and so on.
I don’t know the name or service."
[n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZLxs.png)

Comment: What is the name of the host?  Type "hostname" to find out and use that instead of ubuntu.

Comment: Can you resolve all the hostnames you are using in the configuration?

Comment: during gpssh-keyex, you need to provide a "host list" that contains hostnames only.  It looks like you were feeding gpssh-keyex with "gpinitsystem.config"